# Delphi: why complain about missing method implementation?

Tags: delphi, generics, interface, delphi-xe2

I'd like to use `IEnumerator<T>` instead of `IEnumerator` for a list I'm building. I've tried the following

```
IMyList = interface(IEnumerator<TElement>)
  procedure Add(Element: TElement);
end;

TMyList = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyList )
private
  function GetCurrent: TElement;
  function MoveNext: Boolean;
  procedure Reset;
public
  property Current: TElement read GetCurrent;
  procedure Add(Element: TElement);
end;
```

but to my amazement I'm being told that `TMyList` doesn't implement `GetCurrent`. Why is the compiler telling me that `GetCurrent` is missing when it is clearly not? (For the record, `GetCurrent` is implemented, only omitted here for brevity.) Thanks!

Comment: don't have Delphi anymore, but I presume that you got this error because IEnumerator defines GetCurrent as function that returns object or T not TElement, see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IEnumerator.GetCurrent

Comment: Thanks for the input, Antonio Bakula. Here's how IEnumerator<T> is defined in Delphi:   
IEnumerator<T> = interface(IEnumerator)
  function GetCurrent: T;
  property Current: T read GetCurrent;
end;
So IEnumerator<TElement> would imply GetCurrent : TElement among others ...

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. XE2. :)

Comment: You should implement `IEnumerable<T>` and not `IEnumerator<T>` to make your implementation work with the for in loop. Also if your list is not generic anymore I don't see the point of using said interfaces.

Comment: @StefanGlienke: that's a very good point - I'll be needing that. +1

Comment: @StefanGlienke: yes, your objection to the use of generics here is valid. The reason I did go for the generic kind in the first place, was for compile-time type checking. Perhaps not the weightiest of arguments, but I do consider it to be good practice to be as specific about type as possible. Of course, in this example IMyList.Add would enforce the user to pass only TElements, so it's kind of a "moo point".

Comment: An additional reason I like the generic version, is that IEnumerator asks you to implement GetCurrent (which, according to IEnumerator should return TObject). I prefer that the returned object is of proper type, i.e. TElement in this case. But that's a matter of taste I guess.

Comment: To make an object usable with a for in loop it just needs a GetEnumerator method which returns something (object,record or interface) that itself has the method MoveNext and property Current. (see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_statements)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`IEnumerator<T>` inherites from `IEnumerator` interface. Both of them have `GetCurrent()` method, and one of them is usual method and second is generics `T` method;

so in your class you have to implement both of them `getCurrent():TObject` (from `IEnumerator`) and `getCurrent():T` (from `IEnumerator<T>`);

one small problem is that both methods have the same parameters and you can't simply declare both of them. so you should use aliases:

```
  function getCurrentItem() : TElement; //actual method for IEnumerator<T>
  function GetCurrent():TObject;  //method for IEnumerator
  function IMyList.GetCurrent = getCurrentItem; //alias
```

Take a look at **Method Resolution Clause** at docwiki http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Implementing_Interfaces

so, in your case, code should look like (I marked all methods Abstract):

```
TElement = class(TObject)
end;

IMyList = interface(IEnumerator<TElement>)
  procedure Add(Element: TElement);
end;

TMyList = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyList )
private
  function getCurrentItem() : TElement; virtual; abstract;

  function IMyList.GetCurrent = getCurrentItem;
  function GetCurrent():TObject;  virtual; abstract;

  function MoveNext(): Boolean;   virtual; abstract;
  procedure Reset(); virtual; abstract;
public
  property Current: TElement read GetCurrentItem;
  procedure Add(Element: TElement); virtual; abstract;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks teran! I assumed that IEnumerable<T>.GetCurrent would hide IEnumerable.GetCurrent, an assumption that I in retrospect see is quite wrong. Nice! :)